# ui:include using FaceletsContext

Tags: java, jsf, binding, primefaces, facelets

I'm using PrimeFaces and I have next jsf page:

```
<h:form id="form1111">

            <p:commandLink value="Include Page" actionListener="#{dynaInclBean.includePage}" update="dynInclTabView"/>
            <p:tabView id="dynInclTabView" dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="Somename" binding="#{dynaInclBean.tab}"/>
            </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
```

My backing bean:

```
private Tab tab;

public Tab getTab() {
    return tab;
}

public void setTab(Tab tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
}

public void includePage() throws IOException
{
    FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    faceletContext.includeFacelet(tab, "playerPhoto.xhtml");
}
```

I want to include page to the tab. When I calling inlcudePage() I get an exception:
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException:
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that both tab is not null, and the file is directly in the folder of the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

This construct is indeed not supported in MyFaces. Therein, the `FaceletContext` is only available during view build time (the restore view phase) and is released immediately by end of this phase. It would throw a NPE like that in all other phases because the internal Facelet context is been released and nulled out.

This construct works in Mojarra though.

Your best try is to use `<ui:include src="#{bean.include}">` or multiple conditionally rendered includes. There is still no "holy grail" solution for this problem. The problem is clearly understood, but the solution is hard given the JSF/Facelets lifecycle.

#### See also:

- [How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu)
- [Dynamic ajax navigation with <ui:include>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680192/dynamic-ajax-navigation-with-uiinclude)

Comment: I need to make a tabView with the ability to add and remove tabs, so I need to include page to the tab on the java side

Comment: Just provide a dynamic list of tabs to `<p:tabView value>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961692/how-to-add-button-for-adding-new-tabs-near-last-tab/11962703#11962703