# Prime faces dynamically adding tabs

Tags: ajax, jsf, tabs, primefaces

Is it possible to add dynamic tabs (unrelated tabs) with out reloading the page using prime face.

I want to do some thing like this

http://blog.favrik.com/examples/tabs/

we will have a menu bar, and when a menu is clicked,a dynamic tab to be created.
The tab should load a page(xhtml), the tab should be added  with out full page reloading and no dependency on any managed bean (as we are trying to be maximum stateless using mostly request scope)

I have seen example showing  adding tabs based on bean data.  But in my case each tab are independent (pages)

I have added a sample Image from the current flex application,(trying to migrate it to JSF) on what I am trying to do. Each tab is like a independent screen/xhtml file. No view state saved in server. when a menu item is clicked, a new tab is added with the new screen content. on page reload the tabs will be lost (which we can live with it as we are trying to be stateless)

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: If you populate a form which adds a record to the model behind a tab, then re-render the tabView, yes. Have you seen the Tabview model on the Primefaces showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewModel.jsf

Comment: @7SpecialGems, I don't think OP want to base his `TabView` on a bean-based model

Comment: I've posted an answer to a very simliar question before. Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961692/how-to-add-button-for-adding-new-tabs-near-last-tab/11962703#11962703

Comment: Hi, as Kolossus mentioned, I am not looking for TabView based on a bean model. we are trying to build a stateless application(using request scope, not even view or conversation scope), So if a user clicks on back or refresh button, we don't care, we just load the default page. Each tab should be loading an independent page(xhtml).   if we have a menu for user management, account management etc, when I click a menu for user management, it will load in a tab, again if i click account management, it will load as another tab dynamically.  Each tabs can function independently.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to flesh out your question more with more detail as to **what** you'll place in the tab. But try this :

1. Bind your client side `TabView` to an instance in the backing bean. On the xhmtl side :

   ```
   <p:tabView id="myTabPanel" binding="#{myBackingBean.tabView}" />
   ```

   in the backing bean

   ```
   TabView tabView = new TabView();
   //getter and setter
   ```
2. Implement the snippet below in a method to add a `Tab` as a child of the `TabPanel`

   ```
   TabView tabView = new TabView();
   Tab newTab = new Tab();             //Create new Tab
   newTab.setTitle("Tab Title");       //Set a basic property
   tabView.getChildren().add(newTab);  //Add as a child of the TabView
   ```
3. Use primefaces `RequestContext` to ajax update the view to reflect the new tab

   ```
     RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
     context.update("myTabPanel");
   ```

Alternatively, like 7SpecialGems pointed out, you could simply just bind your `TabView` to a backing bean list and simply add a new item to that list, updating the `TabView` with RequestContext as indicated in 3. above to reflect the changes

Comment: Hi, this may work,but this will be stateful, and we need to use either view or conversation scope. But I want it to be stateless/request scope, Please see the comment i have added above, explaining on what I am trying to do

Comment: If that is the case, then the only way I can see this being achieved is for the tab data to be persisted somewhere and for the backing bean to load this information into a list on request (If the table view is request scope then this will obviously happen by refreshing the page, as the view scope backing bean will read out all the tab data from the data store into a list, and provide it to the tabView). If you are creating new tab data, it has to go somewhere. If you're not happy collating that in session (even with @ViewScoped), then you're pushing it down a layer.

Comment: @7SpecialGems, As mentioned by you, I think we have to  go down the layer.  I do not want the view information to be persisted anywhere. We are doing a POC in migrating a Flex Application to JSF.  In flex, we have SuperTabNavigator component, and in each tab, we load different screen/Flex module.  I am trying to imitate the same in JSF.  In case of flex,server does not have any idea about the client tabs or views. Hope I made it clear on what I am trying to achieve