# How to create <ui:include> tag programmatically?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to create a dynamic TabView in which every tab displays a different xhtml page with help of `<ui:include>` tag.

following is the code snippet where I am trying to do it

```
    Tab tab= new Tab();  
    Portal portal=itr.next();
    tab.setTitle(portal.getPortal_name());
    tab.setId(portal.getPortal_name());
    /*   Code to generate <ui:include> tag
     *   and add it to tab
     */
    tabView.getChildren().add(tab);
```

I  have searched a lot but couldn't find any way to generate `<ui:include>` tag.
Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: There is no corresponding UIComponent class for <ui:include> it is a tag. If you want to change your view dynamically use facelets. Using facelets will make your job easy.

Comment: I had the same issue. Any solution for now?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FaceletContext#includeFacelet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext.html#includeFacelet%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
faceletContext.includeFacelet(tab, "include.xhtml");
```

Note that this construct fails in MyFaces when not running during view build time. It works in Mojarra.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you aware of `<p:tabView value>` which can take a collection? No need to create tabs programmatically. See also e.g. [How to add button for adding new tabs near last tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961692/how-to-add-button-for-adding-new-tabs-near-last-tab/11962703#11962703)